# Not enough space for BuildTools to run - Java - Minecraft plugin test server

Tags: java, server, minecraft

Sorry if the question title was a bit brief, I couldn't think of any other way to word it, sorry if this is an unclear question. But those of you who have coded Java Minecraft plugins before or have created test servers on localhost probably know what I'm talking about. I'm trying to run BuildTools (And install git) with the command
`java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.15`
but I get this error:

```
BuildTools requires at least 512M of memory to run (1024M recommended), but has only detected 247M.
This can often occur if you are running a 32-bit system, or one with low RAM.
Please re-run BuildTools with manually specified memory, e.g: java -Xmx1024M -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.15
```

And yes, I have tried `java -Xmx1024M -jar BuildTools.jar --rev`
and it gives me:

```
Loading BuildTools version: git-BuildTools-7fe9375-122 (#122)
Java Version: Java 8
Current Path: C:\Users\mmein\OneDrive\Desktop\BuildTools\.
Please do not run BuildTools in a Dropbox, OneDrive, or similar. You can always copy the completed jars there later.
```

Ive also tried running the first command after running this one and it still gives the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please do not run BuildTools in a Dropbox, OneDrive, or similar. You can always copy the completed jars there later.
```

`Current Path: C:\Users\mmein\OneDrive\Desktop\BuildTools\.`

It's telling you exactly what to do. You are currently using your OneDrive desktop, Try using this path: C:\Users\mmein\Desktop\ and create the BuildTools folder there with `BuildTools.jar` and run the command.

Comment: Yeah, i figured that out a little bit ago, I thought I left a comment about it but apparently not.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I'll delete the answer later